# Is there a way to define global Makefile (implicit) rules?

Tags: makefile

I can compile a c program `test.c` by running `make test` even if there isn't a Makefile in the directory. That is because make has [built-in implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html).

I want to do the same thing with LaTeX files. I want to type `make test.pdf` without having a Makefile in the directory, and make would search for `test.tex` and build the pdf.

I already know how to define [pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html). I wonder if it is possible to define global pattern rules, so that I don't need to copy the Makefile to wherever I have a Tex file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define environment variable named [MAKEFILES](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#MAKEFILES-Variable), which will list implicitly included Makefiles. That would do what you want, e.g.:

```
$ ls
foo.tex  implicit.mk

$ make foo.pdf
make: *** No rule to make target 'foo.pdf'.  Stop.

$ cat implicit.mk
%.pdf: %.tex
        echo Make $@ from $<

$ export MAKEFILES=implicit.mk
$ make -s foo.pdf
Make foo.pdf from foo.tex
```